# Can't get new NIC working

Tags: ubuntu, networking

OS: Ubuntu server 20.04
NIC: Intel XL710-QDA1
DAC cable: FS "generic" QSFP+
Switch: Brocade ICX-6610-24p

I cannot get this thing to work. Updated firmware. No change. Ifconfig shows nothing but RX errors. This is only after using a static IP address. DHCP wouldn't work. Pings both to and fro to IP addresses on the network. Can't ping "google.com" for example. It won't connect to anything, and nothing will connect to it. Tried the other port on the switch and it doesn't even make a link.

Where should I go from here? Bark of the tree from whom I bought the switch? I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Start by looking into `dmesg`, and showing us what it says about the NIC.

Comment: [    6.613446] i40e 0000:62:00.0 enp98s0: renamed from eth0
[   13.018900] i40e 0000:62:00.0 enp98s0: changing MTU from 1500 to 9014
[   13.727587] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp98s0: link becomes ready
[ 6644.528007] i40e 0000:62:00.0 enp98s0: NIC Link is Down
[ 6821.241499] i40e 0000:62:00.0 enp98s0: NIC Link is Up, 40 Gbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[ 6875.222989] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp98s0: link becomes ready
[ 7059.501868] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp98s0: link becomes ready

Comment: Updated the card's firmware almost right away. Downloaded Intel's driver almost right away, and it's using that. Used a tool to unlock non-Intel optics, even though it's using a DAC cable. Only one of the four 40g ports on the switch seem alive (only one lights up the NIC, the 3 other ones don't do anything).

Comment: I ran into the exact same thing with an XL710 and ICX6610-48P. Frustrating, as CX3 is no longer supported on ESXi 8.

Answer (score 3):

Intel XL710 is known for being one of the crappiest NICs in the whole history of the mankind. Google and you’ll dig out a ton of the horror stories. Intel just keeps chopping off the half baked in silicon features with every single firmware or driver update. Bottom line: You won’t make it work, just throw the damn thing into the trash can. Get yourself some Mellanox CX4LC and live long and happy life.

Answer (score 0):

I never got this working. Things I did:

- Ordered 2 spare DAC cables, one end programmed for Brocade, one end programmed for the XL710
- Went through tons of combinations of settings under ethtool -K
- Went through tons of combinations of settings under ethtool --set-priv-flags (saw one called legacy-rx and thought that would do it, since all my errors were FROM the switch, and they were framing errors. No CRC errors.).
- Bought a second XL710
- Since I had 2 cards, and have 2 servers, linked them together with the "generic" FS DAC. They connected together just fine.
- Took the switch apart and checked out the 40-gig board and its connectors to interface with the motherboard. There was a speck of dirt (around 1.5mm big). Cleaned it out, no change.
- Changed the mode to 4x10 and used one of the breakout ports. Each of the 4 virtual interfaces then worked fine, but that was useless to me.

I wound up buying a Mellanox MCX353A-FCBT and it works fine. So I'm guessing the XL710 is just incompatible with these switches.

Comment: Intel XL710 is legendary for being the worst 10 GbE NIC produced ever. So many software & hardware issues! Buggy drivers, overheats and start dropping packets, Tx/Rx buffers not deep enough, RDMA not working et cetera.